# Use approxfun with each unique element of vector

Tags: r, apply

I am fairly new to R and I like to understand the concept of using the "apply"-family functions to avoid loop and custom functions. Unfortunately I am failing at the very first exercise.

Here is my minimum reproducible example:

```
x <- data.frame(Hours=cbind(c(rep(5,5),rep(6,5),rep(7,5),rep(8,5),rep(9,5))),Price=c(cbind(seq(48,50.4, by=0.1),seq(48,52.8, by=0.2),seq(48,55.2, by=0.3),seq(48,57.8, by=0.4),seq(48,60.0, by=0.5))),Volume=seq(10000:10024))
f1 <- approxfun(x$Volume,x$Price, rule=2)
plot(x$Volume, x$Price)
curve(f1, add=TRUE)
```

However, I would like to perform `approxfun()` with every unique Hour in `x$Hour`.

How would I have to approach this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the idiom is split/apply/combine: split the data, apply the function, combine the results.  R/*plyr/data.table etc has many functions to do this: `fns <- lapply(split(x, x$Hours), function(dat) approxfun(dat$Volume, dat$Price, rule=2)); plot(x$Volume, x$Price); cols <- 1; for(fn in fns) curve(fn, add=TRUE, col=(cols<<-cols+1))`

Comment: I was not aware this was possible to do. Great. This is going to help me a lot. If you can post your comment as an answer I'd like to accept it as answer to this question.

Comment: glad you got it working, feel free to answer if you're motivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution was provided by bunk.

The idiom is *split/apply/combine*: split the data, apply the function, combine the results. R/*plyr/data.table etc has many functions to do this:

```
fns <- lapply(split(x, x$Hours), function(dat) approxfun(dat$Volume, dat$Price, rule=2)); plot(x$Volume, x$Price); cols <- 1; for(fn in fns) curve(fn, add=TRUE, col=(cols<<-cols+1))
```